# Add rules to JSON stringify

Tags: json, typescript

I have a class:

```
class OrderParameterInfo {
Name: string;
Value: string;
```

and I am trying to create a JSON string. By using `JSON.stringify(OrderParameterInfo("foo_name", "foo_value"))` it creates `{"Name":"foo_name","Value":"foo_value"}` however I want it to be more like the python dictionary. So the desired output is `{"foo_name":"foo_value"}`.

Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: you should create another object that has the correct fields, assuming you have `yourObj` originally, something like `let a = {}; a[yourObj.Name] = yourObj.Value;` and then stringify `a`

Answer (score 3):

Certainly, you can create dynamic object keys like this:

```js
const key = 'some_dynamic_key';
const value = 'some_dynamic_value';
const yourObject = { [key]: value }; // { some_dynamic_key: 'some_dynamic_value' }
```

So in order to achieve the result you want, you can easily create a function to do this for you like this:

```js
const orderParameterInfo = (name, value) => ({ [name]: value });

JSON.stringify(orderParameterInfo('foo_name', 'foo_value'));
```